Visual Studio failing to create/setup Node.js project, says its a problem with
I am trying to create a Node.js console application with Visual Studio, but every time I click the "create" button it gives me the following error:

SDK Resolver Failure: "The SDK resolver "NuGetSdkResolver"
failed while attempting to resolve the SDK
"Microsoft.VisualStudio.JavaScript.Sdk/1.0.784122". Exception:
"NuGet.Packaging.Core.PackagingException: Unable to find
fallback package folder '\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages'.
at NuGet.Packaging.FallbackPackagePath Resolver..ctor(String
userPackageFolder, IEnumerable`1 fallbackPackageFolders)
at
Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.NuGetSdkResolver.NuGetAb
straction.GetSdkResult(SdkReference sdk, Object nuGetVersion,
SdkResolverContext context, SdkResultFactory factory)
at
Microsoft.Build.NuGetSdkResolver.NuGetSdkResolver.Resolve(S
dkReference sdkReference, SdkResolverContext
resolverContext, SdkResultFactory factory)
at
Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.SdkResolution.SdkResolverService.TryR
esolveSdkUsingSpecified Resolvers (IReadOnlyList`1 resolvers,
Int32 submissionld, SdkReference sdk, LoggingContext
loggingContext, ElementLocation sdkReferenceLocation, String
solutionPath, String projectPath, Boolean interactive, Boolean
isRunningInVisualStudio, SdkResult&sdkResult,
IEnumerable`1& errors, IEnumerable`1& warnings)"""
\SoftwareDev\NodeJS\NodeConsoleApp1\NodeConsoleApp1
\NodeConsoleApp1.esproj

I am unsure of what this means, so I would appreciate some help.
I've tried reinstalling the relevant Visual Studio build tools to no avail. I was expecting that maybe the problem would have been resolved, and I could create my Node project no issue, but it didn't happen.
Edit: Checked the sln file, and it is completely blank after the error shows up.

The error message you're encountering suggests that Visual Studio is unable to locate a necessary NuGet package due to missing fallback package folders. This issue might arise from a misconfiguration or a missing installation of required components.
You can reinstall the  Node.js development from Visual Studio Installer.
